# Samba folder issue

Tags: linux, samba, file-permissions

I am using Samba to map Linux server on Mac. I have set all the permissions but I am still not able to see the files inside the folder using Samba share. So I am using owner account touches files through Samba I am not able to see the files inside some of the folders even with the admin account. Below is the permissions given to the folder

```
# owner: Owner
# group: staff_group
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:admin_group:rwx
group:staff_group:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:admin_group:rwx
default:group:staff_group:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x.
```

it keeps checking the folder the search circle keeps spinning at the bottom right corner as in below pic.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You haven't uploaded your picture yet :)

Comment: The pic isnt uploading. Basically, it takes lot of time for files to appear

Comment: you can print screen, then when posting, insert image, then paste. You can't crop it this way, though

Comment: @Vylix Thank you. I just did. As you can see in the pic files are not showing up even. It takes a lot of time for files to appear.

Comment: You need reputation to insert image. I've suggested edit to show the image, so just wait a bit.

Comment: @Vylix Can you see the pic now